# How to configure a uWSGI site to use different Python interpreters than what uWSGI was built with? (uWSGI + virtualenv + emperor)

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv, uwsgi

Our app is written for Python 2.7.  It has a virtualenv that is configured to use Python 2.7.  The system's installed uWSGI was built with Python 2.6.  [It seems that this is a problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20026506/using-django-uwsgi-emperor-with-separate-virtualenvs-per-site-nginx-uwsgi)  We could uninstall/reinstall uWSGI to use Python 2.7, but what happens when we eventually have a Python 3 site?  Isn't this what virtualenv is for?  We could install a separate instance of uWSGI in the virtualenv, but it's not clear how that works -- need to activate it at boot time and how might that work with an emperor? Should we use the uWSGI keyword "unprivileged-binary-patch"?

**How do we configure uWSGI so that we can run multiple apps using different Python interpreters?**

We are seeing this problem when launching from uWSGI.

```
Python version: 2.6.9 (unknown, Oct 29 2013, 19:58:13)  [GCC 4.6.3 20120306 (Red
 Hat 4.6.3-2)]
Set PythonHome to /var/local/virtualenv/myapp
Python main interpreter initialized at 0xf86790
python threads support enabled
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 655200 bytes (639 KB) for 8 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
initialized 137 metrics
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/local/myapp/cgi/myapp.wsgi", line 6, in <module>
    from myapp import create_app
  File "./myapp/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app import create_app
  File "./myapp/app.py", line 1, in <module>
    import os
ImportError: No module named os
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
gracefully (RE)spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 2500)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 2521, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 2522, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 2523, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 2524, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 5 (pid: 2525, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 6 (pid: 2526, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 7 (pid: 2527, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 8 (pid: 2528, cores: 1)
metrics collector thread started
*** Stats server enabled on 127.0.0.1:9191 fd: 27 ***
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 2530)
```

The app is written with Flask and is using the create_app pattern to launch it.  The app works fine when using virtualenv and the developer web server built into Flask on port 5000.

The ini file looks like this:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /var/local/%n
callable = create_app
virtualenv=/var/local/virtualenv/%n
wsgi-file = /var/local/%n/cgi/%n.wsgi
master = true
daemonize = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
pidfile = /var/run/uwsgi/%n.pid
http = :9090
```

We want to run the site in emperor mode.  Here is the emperor ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
emperor = /etc/uwsgi/vassals

pidfile = /var/run/uwsgi/%n.pid
daemonize = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
```

Answer (score 2):

The best approach would be having a uWSGI plugin for each python version (like the uWSGI packages in your distro do)

(doc on the old site)
http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/MultiPython

Comment: I tried it and got stuck. To do this, we need to build from source and then know which plugins to also build besides the python plugins. Is there a list? I had partial success with your idea (thank you!) I originally installed uWSGI using pip install http://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-lts.tar.gz  This results in some combination of plugins, but uses default python (which is my problem) Your idea requires installing it from source, but I need to know which other plugins to also compile (I get an error about not having a request plugin this way -- I guess "core" doesn't have that)

Comment: for deploying python apps you only need the python plugin (well one for each python version). You get the no "request plugin loaded" because you did not added the 'plugin' option to your options to tell the uWSGI core which plugin to load

Comment: I tried to add the plugins=python27 line to the vassal's ini file.  uWSGI complains that it can't find that plugin file.  So I built the plugin from the same source that I installed with -- but where to put it?  So I also added the plugins-dir=/place/where/python27/plugin/lives to the vassal's ini file.  That didn't error, but the python version is not being loaded.  It still reports 2.6.X.

Comment: Maybe this build tutorial will help:
https://www.paulox.net/2019/03/13/how-to-use-uwsgi-with-python-3-7-in-ubuntu-18-x/

Answer (score 2):

You can install an uwsgi inside your other python/virtualenv version. Then you can use the uwsgi emperor in stackable mode:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /var/local/%n
callable = create_app
virtualenv=/var/local/virtualenv/%n
wsgi-file = /var/local/%n/cgi/%n.wsgi
master = true
daemonize = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
pidfile = /var/run/uwsgi/%n.pid
http = :9090
unprivileged-binary-patch = /var/local/virtualenv/bin/uwsgi
```

Comment: I don't have any uwsgi file in bin directory of vitualenv

Comment: did you install uwsgi in your venv?
(e.g. `pip install uwsgi`)